# Using PowerShell DSC in Pull mode how do you tell it's finished?

Tags: powershell, dsc

Using PowerShell DSC in Pull mode how do you tell that the set of computers have finished deploying? - For example if the ConfigurationMode=ApplyOnly or ApplyAndMonitor, our operations guys would like to know when it's 'done'.

(We're planning on using the file download manager in our case - perhaps this doesn't have any bearing on the above.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the DSC Compliance or conformance endpoint. This can be installed along with DSC Pull service (REST-based). This provides an oData endoint which has the Status method returning `NodeCompliant` property. This property tell you if the last configuration run was successful or not.

Check this for more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/05/29/how-to-retrieve-node-information-from-pull-server.aspx